# Querying from two different schema tables

Tags: sql, vertica

I have two tables - table1 and table2 - with the same columns in two different schema.

Table1

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+------
a1   | b1   | c1
a2   | b2   | c2
```

and table2

```
col1 | col2 | col3
-----+------+------
a1   | b1   | c1
a2   | b2   | c2
```

How to query from both tables (`schema1.table1` and `schema2.table2`) so that I get the result as:

```
  col1 | col2 | col3
  -----+------+------
   a1  | b1   | c1
   a2  | b2   | c2
   a1  | b1   | c1
   a2  | b2   | c2
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name vertica

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a simple union

```
select col1, col2, col3
from schema_1.table1
union all
select col1, col2, col3
from schema_2.table2
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use union all and get the data from those two tables

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM schema1.dbo.table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM schema2.dbo.table2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the union operator.

More details regarding the union operator can be found at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: Link only answers are usually frowned upon here.